# Make socket resource accessible through several pages in php

Tags: php, sockets, connection, persistent

In PHP, is there any way to create, connect and maintain an open (socket)connection so that the connection object can be accessed on several pages?

Imagine a small windows based client program that connects to its server software when you start it. You can send a couple of commands to the server using buttons(lets say start and stop calculation), and receive confirmations on my input.
In this example, when "started", the server will do some counting/calculations and send some values every second to the client which shows this every second until the server is done with its job or you send the "stop" command. The client will also stay connected until you close the program or click some disconnect-button.

How could this client work as a web client running in PHP on the same box as the server software?

I managed to send commands and receive feedback using socket or pfsockopen, but I'm having trouble maintaining the connection since I don't want to reload the page.

I don't want to reload the page every second, so I figured I can use Ajax to execute PHP scripts to read/write to the server without reloading the page, but the script files I execute on the web server can't find my connection resource. I tried saving the resource in session with no luck.

Alternatively, is there any better way of achieving this?

Also: the server software is an old piece of VB6 software, and the web server is on the same box as the VB6 software. The PHP site will work as an interface.